# how to change language in i3wm

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, i3-wm

i'm new to i3wm and stuck with the config. I wanted to ask how can I change language in i3wm.
I made some search and found some stuff but it's not working in my case.
these are two ways that I found

```
# changing language
exec_always "setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,fa_IR -variant ,, -option 
grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

and

```
exec "setxkbmap -layout en_US,fa_IR"
exec "setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'"
```

I thought maybe I'm not using the proper name for the persian keyboard layout and I don't know how to find the possible options of the languages. Would appreciate if you can help me sort this out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the layout option for Persian is `ir`, use:

```
exec_always "setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ir -variant ,, -option grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything looks more or less OK except for the layout names.

try using the following command to get list of supported keyboard layouts:

```
localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
```

I used answer from this FAQ in the past:
https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4761/keyboard-input-language-problems-want-to-switch-to-greek/index.html

The only difference is that my solution is for 104 keys keyboard and Russian layout.

Exact line that was working for me.

```
exec --no-startup-id "setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru -option grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

You could rather run the command in quotes from command line(applies for the single session) or add to the `~/.config/i3/config` and use  `$mod+Shift+c` to refresh your config.